# An inequality of J. Necas

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

[image]

The above inequality belongs to J. Necas. *Sur les normes equivalentes dans $W^k_p$ et sur la coercivite des formellement positives. Sem. math. sup. Universite Montreal, 102-128 (1966).* But I can't get this article. Can any one help me on proving this? Or are there other references?

I find the proof of the case $k=1,p=2$ in the book *Mathematical tools for the study of the imcompressible Navier-Stokes equations and related models*. And there gives a hint on the case of $k=1,p\neq2,\Omega=\mathbb{R}^d$:characterise the Fourier Multipliers that continuously map $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ into itself. But I'm nor familiar with Fourier Multiplier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

J. Nečas was not the first to establish this inequality
in the special case $k=1$.  Five years earlier, Lamberto Cattabriga, assisted by Giovanni Prodi, proved an equivalent inequality
$$
\|u\|_{0,p}\leqslant C\Bigl(\Bigl|\int\limits_{\Omega}u\,dx\Bigr|
+\sum\limits_{j=1}^d\|\partial_j u\|_{-1,p}\Bigr) \tag{$\ast$}
$$
for a bounded smooth $\,\Omega\,$ in the article "*Su un problema al contorno relativo al sistema di equazioni di Stokes*" in  *Rendiconti del Seminario Matematico della Università di Padova*,  31(1961), p. 308-340 (see p. 312-313  therein).  The inequality $(\ast)$, referred to as a *generalization of Poincaré's inequality*,  can as well be found along with its rather detailed proof in  G.P. Galdi's fundamental monograph

> Galdi, G. P. *An introduction to the mathematical theory of the Navier-Stokes equations*. Steady-state problems. Second edition. Springer Monographs in Mathematics. Springer, New York, 2011. xiv+1018 pp. ISBN: 978-0-387-09619-3 [MR2808162](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2808162)

(see *Exercise* III.3.4 on p. 175 and *Exercise* III.3.10 on p. 191  therein).  For bounded $\,\Omega\,$ satisfying the cone condition,  Galdi's approach to the case $\,k=1$,$\,1<p<\infty\,$ is based on applying the Bogovskii explicit representation formula for the right inverse of the divergence operator with homogeneous boundary data on $\,\partial\Omega$, being the adjoint to the gradient operator $\,\nabla\,\colon L^p(\Omega)\to W^{-1,p}(\Omega)\,$ whose range is closed in $W^{-1,p}(\Omega)\,$ *iff*  the inequality $\,(\ast)\,$ does hold for all $\,u\in L^p(\Omega)\,$ with some constant $\,C>0\,$ independent of $u$.

A relatively trivial case of $\,\Omega=\mathbb{R}^d\,$ is readily solved by employing 
the so-called Bessel potentials along with $L^p$-estimates for the Fourier transform
multipliers.  Namely, let 
$$
\widehat{f}(\xi)=F[f]\overset{\rm def}{=}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d}
f(x)e^{-i(\xi,x)}dx.
$$
By definition, for any integer $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, the space
$$
W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)=\{w\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^d)\,\colon 
F^{-1}\bigl[(1+|\xi|^2)^{m/2}\widehat{w}(\xi)\bigr]\in  L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)\}
$$
with the norm
$$
\|w\|_{m,p}=\bigl\|F^{-1}\bigl[(1+|\xi|^2)^{m/2}
\widehat{w}(\xi)\bigr]\bigr\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)}\,,\quad -
\infty<m<+\infty,\;1<p<\infty,
$$
is the space of Bessel potentials
$$
w(x)=B_m f\overset{\rm def}{=}F^{-1}\bigl[(1+|\xi|^2)^{-m/2}\widehat{f}(\xi)\bigr]
$$
of all functions $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$.  Of course, operators $B_m$ will be potentials in a direct sense if only $m\geqslant 0$. When $\,m<0\,$, the potentials $\,B_m\,$ are to be treated as pseudo-differential operators of the order "$-m$".  The Bessel potentials space $W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ does coincide with the habitual Sobolev space $W^{m,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for any integer $m\geqslant 1$, and with 
$L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)\,$ when $m=0$.  For any integer $k\geqslant 1$ and conjugate exponent $p'=p/(p-1)$, $\,1<p<\infty$,  the dual of the Sobolev space $W^{k,p'}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is identified with the Bessel potentials space 
$W^{-k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

It is clear that the Schwartz space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ will be a dense subspace in $W^{-k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for all integer $k\geqslant 1$ and $\,1<p<\infty$. Hence, 
to prove the lemma in question it just suffices to establish the inequality
$$
\|w\|_{-k+1,p}\leqslant \|w\|_{-k,p}+C\!\sum\limits_{j=1}^d 
\|\partial_j w\|_{-k,p}\quad \forall\,w\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)
\tag{$\ast\ast$}
$$
with some constant $C>0$ depending only on $k,d,p$. Notice that
\begin{align*}
(1+|\xi|^2)^{(-k+1)/2}=(1+|\xi|^2)^{-k/2}+(1+|\xi|^2)^{-k/2}\bigl[(1+|\xi|^2)^{1/2}-1\bigl]\\
=(1+|\xi|^2)^{-k/2}+(1+|\xi|^2)^{-k/2}\frac{|\xi|^2}
{1+\sqrt{1+|\xi|^2}}
\end{align*}
whence follows
$$
(1+|\xi|^2)^{(-k+1)/2}\widehat{w}(\xi)
=(1+|\xi|^2)^{-k/2}\widehat{w}(\xi)-(1+|\xi|^2)^{-k/2}
\sum\limits_{j=1}^d m_j(\xi)F\bigl[{\partial_j}w\bigr]
$$
with functions
$$
m_j(\xi)\overset{\rm def}{=}\frac{i\xi_j}{1+\sqrt{1+|\xi|^2}}\,,\quad j=1,\dots,d,
$$
satisfying the condition
$$
\sup_{\xi\in\mathbb{R}^d}|\xi^{\alpha}\partial^{\alpha}_{\xi}m_j(\xi)|<\infty\,,\quad j=1,\dots,d,
$$
for all multi-indices $\alpha$ such that $|\alpha|\leqslant 1+d/2$,  which is sufficient for $m_j$ 
to be the Fourier transform $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$-multipliers, *i.e.*,
$$
\|F^{-1}[m_j\widehat{\varphi}]\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)}\leqslant 
C_0\|\varphi\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)}
\quad \forall\,\varphi\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d),\;j=1,\dots,d,
$$
with some constant $C_0>0$ depending only on $k,d,p$. 
By definition of the norm in $W^{-k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ now follows $(\ast\ast)$, 
and hence lemma 2.6.

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for that article for weeks, without success, nevertheless concerning the inequality you write, you can find it for $p=2$ in

Necas, J. Direct Methods in the Theory of Elliptic Equations, Springer, 2012, p.186-190.

For $1<p<\infty$ I suppose you can use Marcinkiewicz interpolation, but I'm looking for that article, because I think there is a better method, without using Fouries multipliers directly, that's why I'm interested in this article.

If someone there has the paper, I'd be in debt.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I found a complete proof for the case $p=2$.A reference is provided for other values of $p$. The reference in question is

Pierre Fabrie, Franck Boyer, *Mathematical Tools for the Study of the Incompressible Navier-Stokes Equations and Related Models*, 2012, Springer.

Section IV.1 is devoted to the Nečas inequality.
This question has been asked and answered a long time ago. However, I hope it will help future visitors.